# Retrieve XML attribute value in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

Suppose I need to get the attribute value in Scala. I *can* assume that the attribute is a string (and if it is not this is an error).

Since the `scala.xml` API (`MetaData.get(name: String):Option[Seq[Node]]`) looks rather complex I wrote a helper function:

```
 def attributeValue(e: Elem, aname: String): Option[String] = for {
   seq <- e.attributes.get(aname)
   value <- seq.collectFirst {case Text(txt) => txt}
 } yield value
```

Does it make sense ? How would you change/fix this code

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `\` operator to extract attribute value:

```
  def attributeValue(e: Elem, attributeName: String): Option[String] =
    (e \ s"@$attributeName").collectFirst { case Text(txt) => txt }
```

Please note, in some cases you might want to simplify it even more (as shown below), however in this case the empty string will be returned if attribute is not found (which is probably not what you're after):

```
  def attributeValue(e: Elem, attributeName: String): String =
    (e \ s"@$attributeName").text
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks similar to `e.attributes.get(aname).collectFirst{case Text(txt) => txt}`. I thought that the for-comprehension improves readability.

Comment: BTW, I do not get why `attributes.get` returns `Option` of `Seq[Node]` instead of Option of String.